# How can i find or create thank you page in woocommerece

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am integrating the PayPal payment gateway and it's asking for the return link for thank you page. I see that there is no default page for thank you page. Do I have to create a thank you page and add the shortcode for it and then give its link at the PayPal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your PayPal account use need to set the return url to:

***https://your-website.com/checkout/order-received/***

(Change "your-website" in the url to your own domain)

You can also enable automatically redirect above this field.

Now the customer will automatically return dynamically to the correct receipt page.

I hope this works for you :)

Let me know if it worked!

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, i just want to confirm that will this also add the purchase receipt and all the other details that is generated automatically at the thankyou page for the product that is purchased?